# Requirements for OpenStack Autopilot?

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Could anybody explain me why there is requirements for Open Stack to have

1. two disk for each node
2. 7 machines

3.machines with 2 network cards, one machine with 2 network cards I understand but why second ?

Many thanks in advance for your help & support ;-)

BTW:I have few pcs. of Dell Optiplex 780 with SSD drives. I can't install there 2 HDD. Instead of that I have 5 bay Synology NAS which can be used for storage space. Can use NAS disk storage instead of two drives for each node ?

=======================================================================
Nobody answers and describe why is needed 2 hdd for each maas node ?

## In this example can I use NAS ?

Comment: Thanks for link, but I can't find there any informations why each node should have 2 disks ??? What happened when will be only one HDD for each node. Second thing is answer for my question: How can I use for OpenStack my NAS server with 5 HDD?

Comment: The machines have two drives as one is assigned to the OS and OpenStack Compute (Nova), while the second is assigned to a co-located Ceph OSD storage daemon, in a hyperconverged architecture. If your systems cannot physically host a second drive, for a test run you could use USB Flash drives.